# Trouble with <httpErrors> in web.config for MVC Custom Errors and Local Stack Trace

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7.5, custom-errors

In the past, I am used to using the **customErrors** element in the web.config to specify when to use a custom error page to hide detailed exception information from users.

From what I see now, it is preferred to use the **httpErrors** . I have referenced several different resources including the IIS documentation how to accomplish what I need, but I can't seem to figure it out. The requirements I need to specify in the web.config is the following:

```
1) If HTTP 404 Error
     a) If Local, just return IIS 404 or Yellow Screen of Death (YSOD) or whatever. (It doesn't really matter)
     b) If not local, execute URL /Path/To/My/404/ErrorMVCAction

2) If ANY OTHER HTTP ERROR
     a) Use static error.htm page.
```

Currently, we have the following:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" 
               prefixLanguageFilePath="" 
               path="/Path/To/My/404/ErrorMVCAction" 
               responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

When I navigate to a page that doesn't exist and get a 404, I get my custom error page (I tested this by changing the errorMode to 'Custom'. However, when a 500 occurs, instead of getting the Yellow Screen of Death where I can see a stack trace locally, I get the Blue IIS Error Summary page. An example of this is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same frustrating issue until I realised the httpErrors attribute existingResponse must be set to **existingResponse="PassThrough"**. So try changing your configuration to this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
        <remove statusCode="404" />
        <error statusCode="404" 
               prefixLanguageFilePath="" 
               path="/Path/To/My/404/ErrorMVCAction" 
               responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This certainly solved the equivalent annoying issue for me.